# Pass named arguments to python script through python-shell on node.js without quotes

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x

I am calling a python script using `PythonShell` through this code :

```
let python_options = {
    mode: "text",
    pythonPath: "python",
    scriptPath:"./python/",
    args: ["-fil '"+file_path+"'"]
};
let pyshell = new PythonShell.PythonShell('my_script.py',python_options);
pyshell.on('message', function(message) {
    console.log(message);
});
pyshell.end( function(err,code,signal) {
    if (err) console.log("Error %j", err);
    console.log('The exit code was: ' + code);
    console.log('The exit signal was: ' + signal);

    // console.log("results: %j", results);
    res.send(code);
});
```

then within my Python script I do

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument("-fil", '--file', required=False, default=None)
```

The error message I'm getting when calling the script is

```
my_script.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -fil 'path_to_the_file'
```

My issue is that the shell passes `"-fil path_to_the_file"` to the CLI, which gets interpreted as one argument by `argparse`, instead of `-fil path_to_the_file` which would be correctly interpreted by `argparse`.

How can I remove the quotes in `PythonShell` ?

Comment: have you tried passing it a list with multiple args instead of a list with a string representing all the args? e.g. args: ["-fil", file_path]

Comment: I'm getting the same error unfortunately. When I try myself in the CLI it works even with the quotes though so I'm less confident in my diagnostic now...

Comment: `"-fil " "paht_to_the_file"` works in the CLI in case my comment above was unclear. But the PythonShell call still fails with the same error message.

Comment: try --file instead of fil, let me know what happens, I think your python code is the one that is wrong. Are you sure if you say python my_script.py "-fil " "paht_to_the_file" works? Python should not understand an arg with quotes AFAIK it will take it as a postional arg not as a keyword

Comment: I actually modified my code after I asked the question to remove the shortcuts from the `argparse` instance. So I'm calling it with `--file` already and yes it works in the CLI only. pyhton 3.7 on windows

Comment: so what error are you getting now on the nodejs part instead of my_script.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -fil 'path_to_the_file' that's the key to debugging your issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190234/discussion-between-chapo-and-e-serra).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case it can help anyone, the solution is to do :

```
let python_options = {
    mode: "text",
    pythonPath: "python",
    scriptPath:"./python/",
    args: ["-fil",file_path] // instead of args: ["-fil '"+file_path+"'"]
};
```